# Magento: only existing countries in drop-down filter for "Country" column in Grid View

Tags: filter, grid, country

I have created a custom Grid View with the "Country" column:

```
    $this->addColumn('ship_country', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Country'),
        'index' => 'countrycode',
        'type'  => 'country'
    ));
```

The collection list which is displayed in the grid has only 2 countries: Ireland and UK.

**Problem:** the Filter Header for country column shows the drop-down list with all possible, over 200, countries stored inside Magento.

[image: Filter showing all 247 Magento countries]

**Question:** is it possible to force filter to show only Ireland and UK in the drop-down?

*Like this:*

[image: Preferable filter display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the following code:

```
    $this->addColumn('ship_country', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Country'),
        'index' => 'countrycode',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->getCountries(),
    ));
```

Where Helper `getCountries()` method looks something like this:

```
public function getCountries() {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule/entity')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->group('countrycode');
    $countries = array();
    foreach($collection as $item) 
        $countries[$item->getcountrycode()] = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($item->getcountrycode())->getName();
    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate for your answer.